# set font size of the XML text using XSTL which is in the point

Tags: html, xml, xslt

this is my XML

```
   <P style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; MARGIN: 0pt">
            <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman'; FONT-SIZE: 2pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold">Form</SPAN>
                <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman'; FONT-SIZE:12pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold">10-Q</SPAN>
                <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman'; FONT-SIZE:12pt">10sdfasdfasdf-Q</SPAN>
            </P>
```

and i am fetching the font size of the text using this code XSTL code

```
  <font size="{normalize-space(substring-before(substring-after(@style,'FONT-SIZE:'),';'))}" >
```

and problem is that its not working with the point system if i give the font-size attrb in the integer format in the XML then its working fine like `FONT-SIZE:5;` but its not working with the point and the pixel system.

Answer (score 1):

I think are you asking why doesn't the following work (that is to say, why doesn't it show the font in the expected size).

```
<font size="12px">Hello World</font>
```

The answer is that as per the HTML specification, the **size** attribute on the **font** element only has the possible values of 1 through to 7. It does not support specific pixel or point sizes.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#h-15.2.2

Furthermore, the **Font** element is deprecated. So, you should be really using the **font-size** property in CSS anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
size="{normalize-space(substring-before(substring-after(@style,'FONT-SIZE:'), 'pt'))}"
```

it returns string between `FONT-SIZE:` and `pt`.

Comment: it gives me a number finally but if i set that no to the text than it is always at max size like 12,14,16,18 etc.
and i want point size which is different in all these 12,14,16,18 cases...

Comment: i mean when u execute this code u get string between `font-size` and the `pt` LIKE in string 12pt 18pt u get 12 and 18  and set it in the Font tag the size of the text become according to the `<font size="18">` which is not expected result i want to recognize the 12pt font size

Comment: So, what is the expected result? Please, edit the question and clearly specify the expected result. Without specifying the exact expected result you don't have a question!